# Should I use the pallet_membership to handle dapp user membership? (Differences between smart contracts and blockchain runtime)

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate, polkadot, decentralized-applications

I'm building a dapp based on substrate blockchain runtime and smart contracts. The [pallet_membership](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_membership/index.html) rust module handles adding, removing and tracking accounts membership in a blockchain. Would I use the pallet_membership to handle this or should I create a smart contract instead and create the logic in there to handle user membership in my dapp?

Having trouble distinguishing between smart contracts and blockchain runtimes and what different roles they should assume for a dapp. I know smart contracts are deployed to blockchains and the runtime is the underlying logic of a blockchain, but what are some examples of distinct use cases for each that would be used by the dapp itself.

Here is a list of features my dapp would have and which component I believe should handle:

- User posts, comments, upvotes | **Smart contract**
- User membership | **Blockchain runtime**
- User posts sold and bought as NFT's | **No idea...**

Answer (score 0):

There is this entry on substrate.io which may clarify your doubts. https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/smart-contracts/#smart-contracts-vs-runtime-development